# Does angular 2 have a cacheFactroy?

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I wonder if there is cacheFactory in angular2? If there is, can anyone provide some technical tutorials? Simple introduction about how to use it will be very appreciated!.

P.S: Now, I am trying to move my angular1 project to angular2, I have got a problem with using cacheFactory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In angular2 you can use this [CacheFactory](https://github.com/jmdobry/CacheFactory) node module and below code is example of using this CacheFactory.

```
import { CacheFactory } from 'cachefactory';

const cacheFactory = new CacheFactory();
let cache;

// Check whether cache metadata has been initialized
// on every page refresh.
if (!cacheFactory.exists('my-cache')) {
  // Create the cache metadata. Any previously saved
  // data will be loaded.
  cache = cacheFactory.createCache('my-cache', {
    // Delete items from the cache when they expire
    deleteOnExpire: 'aggressive',

    // Check for expired items every 60 seconds
    recycleFreq: 60 * 1000
  });
}

cache.put('/books/1', { title: 'BookOne', id: 1 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular2 doesn't have cacheFactory like Angular1, but you could use [CacheFactory](https://github.com/jmdobry/CacheFactory) as a replacement.